# What good software or scripts are available for managing users and subscriptions on our website?

Tags: php, mysql, membership, subscriptions

Ok so it's not exactly a programing question but does anyone know or have experience with looking for a system for managing users on a website we are building? what is the shortlist of good feature rich secure solutions. we need Php and mysql integration and payment support for main credit cards. We will also want to be able to track users and generate reports about usage, subscription etc, create and send batch emails etc.

It would also be great to have the ability to integrate customer support with this so we can view support tickets raised by users.

cheers

we are running PHP, mysql on an IIS server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Member tracking, I've been pretty happy with AMember

[www.amember.com](http://www.amember.com)

Their forum is pretty good in terms of support.

For credit card internet payment gateway, Authorize.net all the way

Comment: We have gone with aMember and very happy with the product and service.

Answer (score 0):

Using LDAP seems like a reasonable solution.